Space being used by / root filesystem
I'm trying to find the space being used by the FS "/dev/mapper/rhel-root", it has only 5GB, but when i try to find every file on /, the output shows a 8.6G worth of files in the directory, how can this space be adressed? What am i missing?
[root@- ~]# df -h /
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root  5.0G  4.7G  349M  94%
[root@- ~]# find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -exec du -h --total {} + | sort -h | tail -n1
8.6G    total


OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.9 (Ootpa)


show the output of du -h -d 1 / and use it for the bigger folder in the same way and report the output please

Total size of files is larger than the filesystem? Easy. Sparse (and compressed) files and hard links. Use ls -lshR to see the real allocation, to spot it all; the first number will be size that the file is consuming on disk (in KiB, if you run without -h), and there'll be number of links to a file in third column (after modes) — if it's not a directory but the number is larger than 1, that file could have been counted multiple times.

Your command is flawed.
Let's check it out one by one.
find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -exec du -h --total {} +

You find every file and directory on the root filesystem, and you thought about using -xdev to skip other filesystems, but this doesn't help in this case, because one of the found directories is / itself.
sort -h 

Now you sort the results, so the biggest amount is at the end
tail -n1

And you only show the last result.
Now where is the problem? The biggest result is the du -h run of / of course, and with this run you let it accumulate all files and folders of all mountpoints.
So, you basically get the result of du -hs /, but additionally you let find walk through the complete directory structure without additional use.
You could add the argument -mindepth 1 to find to skip /, but other mountpoints will still show up in the search result and will be processed by du, so you are just moving the problem to a different place. du also has the -x argument to stay on the same filesystem, but again, some of your search results will be mountpoints of other filesystems and du will use them as a starting point, so they will show up again at the end.
If you want a comfortable method to find the largest files and directories I recommend ncdu, which can be executed with the -x argument to skip other mountpoints.

Thank you! I will try ncdu
